# What happens if I buy an early access game and it comes out?

Tags: steam

What happens if I buy an early access game and it comes out?

I am thinking about buying an early access game on steam, but I don't know if I'll get the full version when it comes out.

Answer (score 8):

There is no full version. You can think of early access as a message that says "this game isn't complete yet, but you can buy it now if you want". So, basically, you'll keep it when it gets out of early access.

Comment: Also please note that it is possible that a DLC comes out before the game gets completed, and you will have to buy that DLC separately.
(e.g. ARK: Scorched Earth - Expansion Pack)

Comment: Or it's also possible that that game will never be finished and will stay in early access.